# Show currency in gridview in European Format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

My gridview in asp.net has a column that shows currency in Euro format which is 89.483,00

I am aware how to format the strings but not sure how to get the currency data in row databound event and modify the same and send back to the gridview.

String format that goes for Euro format is as;

```
String.Format("{0:0.0,0}", temp1) // here temp1 would hold the non-Euro format currency data
```

Comment: If you have the correct culture then its just `String.Format("{0:C}", temp1);` What is the Culture used ?

Comment: I'm aware of string.format.. pls read my question

Comment: Am I reading this right that the problem you're having is getting the data on Bind and formatting it, not making the string? If that's the case, can you show what you have in the gridview and for the row databound event. If not... ignore this, it's early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that you can set the culture for the site e.g. in web.config and not have to worry about doing this for every single string?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: Yes! what culture would go for European nations?

Comment: I don't think Europe has a consistent number format. Off the top of my head, I know that Denmark and Sweden have different formats for ordinal numbers, for instance.

Comment: I don't know the details, but if you have users from all of those 3 countries, do you have a strategy for detecting which country a user is from? Or is the site always in the same language / same culture specific settings?

Comment: site is in same culture specific settings

Comment: I would just go with a culture that seems to give all the settings that you want then, e.g. German or French. If you really need a custom culture with some mixture of date and number formats that does not exist in a real country, you can make one by following this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work for you.

You can create your specific number format which would be used for display like

```
decimal currval = 89483.00M;
NumberFormatInfo ninfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").NumberFormat;
// change as you require
ninfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator=",";
ninfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator=".";
//you can also set the currency symbol 
string curr = currval.ToString("C", ninfo);
```

This should get you the currency along with the number